# Problems with a Web-Scrapping in Python "AttributeError: 'NoneType'"

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following problem when webscraping a shein page.

In general the problem is with attributes and in relation to - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' -

If any of you have faced this problem, I would like to know your suggestions for a solution.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Define the URL of the Shein category you want to scrape
url = "https://www.shein.com.mx/style/Women-Clothing-sc-001121425.html?ici=mx_tab01navbar04&src_module=topcat&src_tab_page_id=page_select_class1686667964514&src_identifier=fc%3DWomen%60sc%3DROPA%60tc%3D0%60oc%3D0%60ps%3Dtab01navbar04%60jc%3DitemPicking_001121425&srctype=category&userpath=category-ROPA"  # Replace "xxxxx" with the desired category code

# Send a GET request to the URL and retrieve the page content
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Create empty lists to store the scraped data
products = []
prices = []
urls = []

# Find all product items on the page
product_items = soup.find_all("div", class_="product-list-v2")

# Extract information from each product item
for item in product_items:
    # Extract product name
    product = item.find("div", class_="S-product-item__name").text.strip()
    print(product)
    products.append(product)

    # Extract product price
    price_element = soup.find("span", class_="normal-price-ctn__sale-price")
    price = price_element.text.strip()
    print(price)

    #price = item.find("span", class_="normal-price-ctn__sale-prices").text.strip()
    print(price)
    prices.append(price)
    
    # Extract product URL
    product_url = "https://www.shein.com.mx" + item.find("a", class_="S-product-item__link")["href"]
    print(product_url)
    urls.append(product_url)

# Create a DataFrame from the scraped data
data = {
    "Product": products,
    "Price": prices,
    "URL": urls
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel("shein_data.xlsx", index=False)
```

I get the following error:

```
Blusa con estampado de manga murciélago
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mf/q3n84d_56kqg93knb4lwwpk40000gn/T/ipykernel_92687/3928343523.py in 
     26 
     27     # Extract product price
---> 28     price = item.find("span", class_="normal-price-ctn__sale-prices").text.strip()
     29     print(price)
     30     prices.append(price)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

According to me the problem lies in reading the following line of code:

```
<span role="contentinfo" aria-label="Precio$MXN171.00" class="normal-price-ctn__sale-price" tabindex="0">$MXN171.00</span>
```

Can you provide me with any suggestions to solve this problem?

Greetings,
Alexis

I am hoping to be able to correctly get the price for each product identified on the Shein page.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: The problem is the selector, `soup.find("span", class_="normal-price-ctn__sale-price")` failed to select any elements. And therefore, it returns `None`, which would therefore lead to the scenario you have.

For suggestions on debugging, you can download the HTML that the server actually returned to you went you are using a request like this:

```py
response = requests.get(url)
with open("test.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

And open this file with your browser, then inspects the elements with a web console. The above conclusion is made by evaluating `document.querySelector('span.normal-price-ctn__sale-price')` in the JS Repl.

And honestly, you can't scrape this webpage with `request`, because the price data is simply hydrated in the HTML content. This page needs a browser to run the JavaScript and render the content in order to display the price data, and the only choice is to render it with a browser and parse it (unless you would like to reverse-engineer their XHR request API, which can be done by inspecting the Network > Fetch/XHR section of the developer console).

I would suggest you use `selenium`/`playwright` for this problem. Check out their documentation here:

1. Playwright: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro
2. Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/